# Can someone identify this transistor and/or resistor component?

Tags: transistors, resistors, identification, symbol

I stumbled upon a weird transistor or resistor component which I can't place. Here is a simplified version of the circuit:

[image: weird transistor]

I am pretty sure that the transistor on the bottom is an N-MOS transistor which pulls `out` low if `in` is high. The weird component at the top seems to serve as pull up resistor but looks more like a transistor than anything.

Can someone identify the component?

*Note: I saw the component on a presentation slide which I don't have access to. I had recreated the circuit from my notes, and thus can't provide more information.*

Comment: The resistor at the top could be a potentiometer. Without seeing the original circuit, it'd just be a guess though. Any idea what the application was? As for the bottom component, while it *could* be a mosfet, its a very strange way of drawing it, so again, the whole circuit, or the original would be needed to make a better guess.

Comment: @mcg I am very bad at drawing; the lines on the bottom are supposed to be zigzag like the symbol of a resistor. It was used just like that, the only difference was that there were a lot of transistors in parallel between out and ground (I only drew one).

Comment: How certain are you that they were transistors? The resistor component could be a potentiometer, which could mean it was used as a pullup, although it doesn't make sense why it wouldn't be a fixed resistor, which makes it a bit confusing for me, so I wouldn't like to say for sure. Is there no way you can get hold of the original? I think it would be a big help for clarification

Comment: Possibly a "pinch resistor".

Comment: context would help

Comment: @russell It was a programmable matrix where you can add transistors between the output and ground, realizing a logic function on the output. I am pretty sure that the accepted answer is correct as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like NMOS transistor being used in depletion mode as an active resistive pull-up.

See Wikipedia: [Depletion-load NMOS logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depletion-load_NMOS_logic).

Comment: That must be it. *"[...] A depletion-mode device with gate tied to the opposite supply rail is a much better load than an enhancement-mode device, acting somewhere between a resistor and a current source. [...]"* from the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depletion-load_NMOS_logic#Depletion-mode_transistors).